# Odd behaviour with eloquent find() on a fresh laravel install

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I started a fresh Laravel install (windows + Largon + Laravel 7.11), made the first migration for Users table and seeded the database like this (dafaut USer factory)

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class,10)->create();
    }
}
```

I got an  odd behavior with Eloquent find()

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    \App\User::find(1)->dump();
    \App\User::where('id',1)->dump();
    \App\User::find([1])->dump();
});
```

The first one is not working as expected, not getting User with id #1.

```
"select * from `users`"
[]
"select * from `users` where `id` = ?"
array:1 [▼
  0 => 1
]
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1192 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Can someone help me understand the behavior of the first one?